# PubSub with CustomAttributes - Receiver function is not invoked but a json parse exception is coming up

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Google Cloud and to PubSub Service.

I have implemented a simple CustomAttributeReceiver in the lines of below sample code

https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub/blob/master/samples/snippets/src/main/java/pubsub/PublishWithCustomAttributesExample.java

How ever i am getting the below exception

*com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected STRING but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path $ at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:944) at
com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:1003) at
com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.NewBackgroundFunctionExecutor$TypedFunctionExecutor.serviceLegacyEvent(NewBackgroundFunctionExecutor.java:257) at
com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.NewBackgroundFunctionExecutor.serviceLegacyEvent(NewBackgroundFunctionExecutor.java:343) at*

Can someone throw light on what i am missing here?

**Publisher side**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.google.api.core.ApiFuture;
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.TopicName;
import PubSubMessage;


            TopicName topicName = TopicName.of(projectId, topicId);
        System.out.println("informListenersAboutSucessfulRegisteration=" + topicName);
        Publisher publisher = null;
        try {
            publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(topicName).build();
            PubSubMessage newUserRegisterMsg = new PubSubMessage();
            Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
            attributes.put(PubSubMessage.newUserLanguage, newUserLanguage);
            newUserRegisterMsg.setAttributes(attributes);
            ByteString data = ByteString.copyFromUtf8("NewUserRegisteration");
            PubsubMessage pubsubMessage = PubsubMessage.newBuilder().setData(data).putAllAttributes(attributes).build();
            ApiFuture<String> messageIdFuture = publisher.publish(pubsubMessage);
            String messageId = messageIdFuture.get();
            System.out.println("Published message ID: " + messageId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(PubSubMessenger.name).log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception while publishing message", e);
        } finally {
            if (publisher != null) {
                publisher.shutdown();
                publisher.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            }
        }
```

**Receiver side**

```
    import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
    import java.util.Base64;
    
    import com.google.cloud.functions.BackgroundFunction;
    import com.google.cloud.functions.Context;
    import PubSubMessage;

    
public class SendEmailFromSendGrid implements BackgroundFunction<PubSubMessage> {
    public SendEmailFromSendGrid() {
    }

    public void accept(PubSubMessage message, Context context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("invoked accept");
        String name = "World";
        if (message != null && message.getData() != null) {
            name = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(message.getData().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)),
                    StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("Hello %s!", name));
        return;
    }
}
```

**PubSubMessage Definition**

```
    import java.util.Map;

    public class PubSubMessage {

    public static final String newUserLanguage = "userLanguage";

    private String data;
    private Map<String, String> attributes;
    private String messageId;
    private String publishTime;

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    public void setAttributes(Map<String, String> attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }

    public String getMessageId() {
        return messageId;
    }

    public void setMessageId(String messageId) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }

    public String getPublishTime() {
        return publishTime;
    }

    public void setPublishTime(String publishTime) {
        this.publishTime = publishTime;
    }
}
```

**THANK YOU**

Comment: Can you share your code to reproduce the minimal example on our side?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere pl find the same in the question now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you print the `message.getData()` value? Are you sure that is still in b64 format? Most of client library automatically convert to string the content.

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere The first System.out.println("invoked accept"); itself is not getting invoked. Not sure if its PubSub internal conversions before invoking this accept function and I am missing some format while sending PubSub message

Comment: Impossible to reproduce... Can you share the Java imports also? (top of the file)

Comment: Added imports @guillaumeblaquiere. Thank you.

Comment: Which version of Function Framework do you use in your dependencies? did you try with a message manually pushed in the topic? I can't find what's wrong with your Background  function!

Comment: import com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.TopicName;    Using this imports, Version 1. Tried with publishing single message from the Google console. Still getting the same exception.

Comment: And how do you deploy your function?

Comment: Using Google cloud console only.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere redid the whole exercise and it is working now. Only difference is added default constructor in PubSubMessage. I am closing this. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was provided by @user1241724 in the comment section:

> Redid the whole exercise and it is working now. Only difference is
> added default constructor in PubSubMessage.